# Error when trying compile kernel samsung for nethunter

Tags: android, linux-kernel

everything is done when writing the default commands:

```
export ARCH=arm64
export SUBARCH=arm64
export CROSS_COMPILE=`pwd`/toolchain64/bin/aarch64-linux-android-
export ANDROID_MAJOR_VERSION=q

make exynos7885-a30s_defconfig
```

but when i finish building and writing [ make -j8 ] command
it's showing me this error:

```
/bin/sh: 1: ../root/kernel/toolchain/bin/aarch64-linux-android-gcc: not found
make[1]: *** [Kbuild:20: kernel/bounds.s] Error 127
make: *** [Makefile:1086: prepare0] Error 2
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
  HOSTCC scripts/genksyms/lex.lex.o
  HOSTCC scripts/dtc/dtc-lexer.lex.o
  HOSTCC scripts/dtc/dtc-parser.tab.o
  cc scripts/mod/empty.o
/bin/sh: 1: ../root/kernel/toolchain/bin/aarch64-linux-android-gcc: not found
make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:278: scripts/mod/empty.o] Error 127
make[1]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:484: scripts/mod] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
  HOSTCC scripts/selinux/genheaders/genheaders
  HOSTCC scripts/selinux/mdp/mdp
  HOSTLD scripts/dtc/dtc
  HOSTLD scripts/genksyms/genksyms
make: *** [makefile:576: scripts] Error2
```

previously i had an ANDROID_MAJOR_VERSION problem
and i found the solution in build_kernel.sh file
and now i am facing this unpleasant problem

any help to solve this problem would be big for me.